# Texture in Godot Doesn't 100% Showed Up

Tags: graphics, 3d, scene, godot

Anyone know why does my Godot viewport and scene looking like these? What should I do to make it right?
[image]
[image]

Comment: See [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). Edit: if that is not what you mean, please elaborate. I think those are regular spatial materials, which makes me wonder if it is caused by duplicate geometry.

Comment: If you have mesh instances without materials with the same geometry, remove those. Otherwise, if you only have meshes with materials, then try merging vertex by distance in blender and importing again.

Comment: @Theraot You were right, it's a z-fighting. Thank you so much. I've deleted the other mash and now it looks normal!